# Use row reduction to prove that $\det A^t=\det A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This exercise is from Artin Algebra:

> Use row reduction to prove that $\det A^t=\det A$.

I thought to work out this way: Since $A$ has to be square, the row reduced echelon form (rref) can be either $I$ or may have bottom row equal to $0$. So, $I=E_k\cdots E_1 A$ if rref of $A$ is identity. Since $\det E=\det E^t$ if $E$ is elementary matrix, we see that $\det A=\det A^t$ when $A$ invertible. If $A$ not invertible then $A^t$ is also non-invertible, and in this case $\det A=\det A^t=0$.

But I saw that this is exactly how $\det A^t=\det A$ proved in main body of text. Then why Artin asks to use row reduction to prove that $\det A^t=\det A$ again in exercise? I think there is another proof using row reduction to arrive at same result.

Comment: One cannot in general get $I$ as a rref, one has to use the **column** operations too. Maybe this is the difference between the main body and the exercise?